# Linear voltage regulator outputs 3.6 volt instead of 5.0 volt

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

A 5 V linear regulator supplies a 5 V constant output irrespective of load. Is that so?

I am asking this question because in a linear regulator circuit in a load condition it is maintaining a constant 5 V, but when a further circuit is connected the output of the regulator is showing 3.6 V.

Comment: Draw the circuit telling us what circuit you add. Most likely causes are that the input voltage is too low or it is going into current limit as pointed out by the answer below

Comment: _"irrespective of load"_ is obviously never correct.

Comment: Further schematic is hell of a circuit which is not at all easy to trace. When the out put of the regulator is disconnected from further circuit it is showing 5v, but when i connect the circuit to the output of regulator the voltage is immediately dropping to 3.6. I am guessing the load is drawing too much current. I think need to check with the data sheet for max output current.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A 5 V linear regulator supplies a 5 V constant output irrespective of load. Is that so?

**No!**

A 5 V linear regulator supplies a 5 V constant output *if all the necessary condditions listed in its datasheet are met*.

There are a number of such conditions, including maximum output current, minimum input voltage, temperature, input voltage variations, input and output capacitances, etc.  The datasheet will also define other parameters, like how constant the "constant" output voltage really is over time, temperature, input voltage variations, load variations, and other parameters.  As always to know what a part can do, **read the datasheet**.  That really should have been obvious.

Most likely when your "futher circuit is connected", the total output current spec is being violated, or the input voltage to the regulator drops below the minimum requirement.

Answer (score 6):

The 5V linear regulator will have a limit on how much current it can supply to the load. When this limit is reached the output voltage will typically drop to a lower value. There are multiple factors which will set the limit of the current that the regulator can provide.

1. The regulator component itself may impose a current limit. Sometimes this current limit is adjustable depending upon the components and/or circuitry used.
2. The input supply to the 5V regulator may be limited in how much current that it can source. In a linear regulator the sourced current is generally close to the output load current with only a small amount of the input current used to bias the regulator circuit/component itself. The source voltage itself may decrease as the load current gets too high.
3. Often the input to a linear regulator is supplied from an unregulated power source where the voltage is higher for low current loads and lower for high current loads. If the load current on the 5V regulator gets higher the input voltage may fall to a level outside the operating range for the 5V regulator and this will cause the 5V output to not be able to stay in regulation. Linear regulators have a specified input to output voltage differential that must be maintained above a minimum amount to remain in regulation.
4. Linear regulators operate, as indicated above, with a voltage differential between the input and output. This voltage difference multiplied by the load current in Amps equates to Watts of power dissipated in the regulator and can cause them to get HOT. Some regulators have a thermal shutdown circuit that cuts off the regulator or limits through current to keep the regulator from burning up. Depending upon the type of circuit/component this may appear as a lowered output voltage or a complete output shutoff.